# Как удалить Visual Studio и все ее компоненты?

Tags: visual-studio, ide

После удаления Visual Studio остается туча компонентов от нее.

Есть ли способ удалить все компоненты от Visual Studio не удаляя их по одному через "Удаление программ"?

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте [Visual Studio Uninstaller](https://github.com/Microsoft/VisualStudioUninstaller/releases)

Comment: Почему-то не все удалилось. Например, пак языков остался, Microsoft VS Tools for Applications 2015...